# chaining jQuery Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization, deferred

i got problems with synchronizing timer functionalities with jquery deferred.
i wrote a function that shows a tooltip after a timeout and removes it after another timeout.
if i call it twice it works but the third call is executed immediatly after the second.
what made i wrong?

here is the function that is called 3 times:

```
function tutorial($element, qtipConfig, startTimeout, stopTimeout) {

    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    window.setTimeout(function() {

        // tooltip
        var qtip = $element.qtip(qtipConfig);
        // api
        var qtipApi = $element.qtip('api');
        // show tooltip
        qtipApi.show();

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            qtipApi.hide();
            dfd.resolve();
        }, stopTimeout);

    }, startTimeout);

    return dfd.promise();
};
```

here is how this function is called:

```
    tutorial($('.mybutton'), qtipConfig, 1000, 2000)
    .then(
        function() {
            return tutorial($('.button2'), qtipConfig, 1000, 2000);
        })
    .then(
        function() {
            return tutorial($('.button3'), qtipConfig, 1000, 2000);
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Chaining the then() calls like that still makes them apply to the first promise.

Comment: Only in older versions of jQuery.  Which version of jQuery are you using?  $.Deferred() didn't comply to the A+ Promise for .then() until 1.8.  Earlier versions you need to use .pipe() instead of .then().

Comment: @MikeEdwards - that's actually correct, from 1.8 up this should work just fine ?

Comment: It looks like correct usage to me given the _new_ behavior of .then() since 1.8, yes.

Comment: Tested it -> http://jsfiddle.net/2zauJ/1/ seems to work ?

Comment: Yes it depends on the version. i actually used 1.7.2 :-(. Thank you.